# How to handle 403 forbidden error in spring boot annotation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, annotations, wildfly

I am facing a problem in handling 403 forbidden problem in spring boot. As i have handled it by my class extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter  to customize .It is giving me as output forbidden. It should redirect to 403 url but its not working. I am beginner and don't know where its wrong.

```
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        ctx.register(SecurityConfiguration.class);  
        ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);  
        //ctx.register(SecurityConfiguration.class);
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(ctx);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);


        Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);  
        dynamic.addMapping("/data/*");  

        dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    }
}
```

and My AppConfig class

```
package com.portal.spring.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.portal")
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

and security config

```
package com.portal.spring.config;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final Logger log= Logger.getLogger( SecurityConfiguration.class.getName() ); 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new AccessDenyHandler());
        }
}
```

and accessdenyhandler

```
package com.portal.spring.config;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandler;

public class AccessDenyHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException arg2) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendRedirect("//403");  
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe more. Why do you think it is not working

Comment: @SangramJadhav...I dont know there is no exception...Is my way correct to handle 403 forbidden problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is My AccessDenied Handler. I have explicitly delegated to Spring AccessDeniedHandler implementation but I have some CSRF related stuff that I need to handle. That piece is not included in below code as it is app specific. Other code like SecurityConfig is similar to what I have used

```
public class MyAccessDeniedHandler implements AccessDeniedHandler {

    private AccessDeniedHandlerImpl accessDeniedHandlerImpl = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();

    public void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            AccessDeniedException accessDeniedException) throws IOException, ServletException {

        //Some CSRF related code 

        // Then call accessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle to handle request
        accessDeniedHandlerImpl.handle(request, response, accessDeniedException);
    }

    /**
     * The error page to use. Must begin with a "/" and is interpreted relative to the current context root.
     *
     * @param errorPage the dispatcher path to display
     *
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the argument doesn't comply with the above limitations
     * @see AccessDeniedHandlerImpl#setErrorPage(String)
     */
    public void setErrorPage(String errorPage) {
        // You can set custom error page here 
        accessDeniedHandlerImpl.setErrorPage(errorPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your support.But  Did you run the example...Even yet it is giving me as html output forbidden..i just want to customize it